# How can I have variable assertions in Perl?

Tags: python, perl, debugging, assertion

How can I check that a variable has a specific value in Perl? Is there a command to stop a script's execution to look up some of its variables?

I wonder if I can use the Pythonic practice of inserting:

```py
assert 0, (foo, bar)
```

to debug scripts in a debuger-less way?

Answer (score 12):

A quick CPAN search suggests [Carp::Assert](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carp::Assert).

Comment: +1 for typing in more characters faster than I did. I am going to edit the URL to be version agnostic though.

Comment: I was going to comment on your answer about the photo finish. As for the URL, I constantly forget that, so thanks.

Comment: @SinanÜnür Wow, actually by **one second**!  Haven't seen that yet :)

Answer (score 9):

See [Carp::Assert](http://metacpan.org/pod/Carp::Assert):

> ```
> use Carp::Assert;
>
> $next_sunrise_time = sunrise();
>
> # Assert that the sun must rise in the next 24 hours.
> assert(($next_sunrise_time - time) < 24*60*60) if DEBUG;
>
> # Assert that your customer's primary credit card is active
> affirm {
>     my @cards = @{$customer->credit_cards};
>     $cards[0]->is_active;
> };
> ```

Answer (score 5):

[Smart::Comments](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Smart::Comments) are nice.

Comment: Smart::Comments++ When used with the -ENV switch, it's a fantastic tool for this sort of thing. Much better than having to strip all the tests out before going to production, as someone else suggested.

Answer (score 3):

There is a script at [PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=391780) that introduces a fast assert method.

Speed is important since Perl is interpreted and any inline checks will impact performance (unlike simple C macros for example)

---

I am not sure if these things are going to be directly usable.

- there is [Test::Harness](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test::Harness) in default installs. Here [is a starter tutorial](http://tomacorp.com/perl/harness/index.html). The more recent module is [TAP::Harness](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?TAP::Harness)
- A slower version along the lines you talk is [Sub::Assert](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sub::Assert)

---

Ok! This is what i was looking for -- [PDF Warning: Test-Tutorial.pdf](http://www.wgz.org/chromatic/perl/Test-Tutorial.pdf). The `Test::Harness` is used for writing Perl module tests.

Answer (score 3):

```
$var_to_check =~ /sometest/ or die "bad variable!";
```

I tend to throw things like this in my code, and later use a find and replace to get rid of them (in production code).

Also, '[eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html)' can be used to run a section of code and capture errors and can be used to create exception handling functionality.   If you are asserting that a value is not 0, perhaps you want to throw an exception and handle that case in a special way?

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( $next_sunrise_time > 24*60*60 ) { warn( "assertion failed" ); } # Assert that the sun must rise in the next 24 hours.
```

You can do this if you do not have access to Perl 5.9 which is required for [Carp::Assert](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Carp%3a%3aAssert).